# django i18n does not translate some strings

Tags: django, internationalization, nginx

I am trying to add translations for some strings in a django application running under nginx. I run makemessages and that updates the django.po for the specified language, I can see with rosetta that the translations are correct and there are no fuzzy items and I run compilemessages. However when I swtiched to the language I added the translations for, only the previous translations are shown but not the new strings. I also stopped and started nginx but that had no effect.

Comment: Are you sure the django process is restarted?

Comment: I thought that stopping nginx would also stop the django process but I'll double check to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end the problem was that the django code was running in a separate process, using FastCGI, so that a restart of nginx had no effect. Instead I had to restart the FastCGI process with a script I found:

/etc/init.d/django site_name restart